# How to create lists using for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

What I want to get is

[a][b][c]

Getting each index from an array a=[a,b,c]. I’m using this to approach a value in dictionary.

All I could find was .append() but this returns me [a,b,c] not [a][b][c]

This is the function that I made

```py
Def loop():
   Newlist = []
   for i in a:
      Newlist.append(i)
   return Newlist
```

Comment: When you say you want to "get" `[a][b][c]` - do you mean you want to print that? Or do you mean you want a variable that has a lists of lists `[[a],[b],[c]]`?

Comment: You can get [a][b][c] it not valid python syntax are you trying to get the list [[a], [b], [c]]?

Comment: Get [a][b][c] to get the value inside multiple dictionaries. 
For ex) ‘return a[b][c]’ would be ‘d’

Comment: You should really include example input and output in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You want to append a list of one value, not a single value. i.e.

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> new_list.append([1])
>>> new_list.append([2])
>>> new_list.append([3])
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

So in the method you'd do something like this:

```
def loop():
    new_list = []
    for i in a:
        new_list.append([i])
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a new list inside the loop that gets reset each time, add your variable, then add the new list to the parent list.

You can also grab individual lists from the parent list using the following: Newlist[1]

```
Def loop():
   Newlist = []
   for i in a:
      temp_list = []
      temp_list.append(I)
      Newlist.append(temp_list)
   return Newlist
```